# Javascript повторный запуск таймера

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть

```
<div class="counter"></div>
```

И есть javascript

```
var i = 10;
onTimer();
function onTimer() {
    $('.counter').html(i);
    i--;
    if (i < 0) {
        $('.counter').html('<a href="#" onclick="return onTimer();">Выслать код повторно</a>');
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(onTimer, 1000);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Не получается сделать так, что бы можно было по истечении времени запустить таймер заново. 
Вероятно сам по себе подход не верный. Подскажите что подправить?
[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/t6zjbf3a/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В коде вопроса не хватает восстановления значения счетчика.

```js
var i = 10;
onTimer();

function onTimer() {
  $('.counter').html(i);
  i--;
  if (i < 0) {
    $('.counter').html('<a href="#" onclick="return onTimer();">Выслать код повторно</a>');
    i = 10; // ЗДЕСЬ
  } else {
    setTimeout(onTimer, 200); // 200 вместо 1000, чтобы так долго не ждать
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="counter">

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t6zjbf3a/1/

Comment: Спасибо большое!)